# Mapping a List-Value pair to a key-value pair with PySpark

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark

I am working on a problem where I have to convert around 7 million list-value pairs to key-value pairs by using map() function in PySpark where the length of the list used in given list-value pair can be at most 20.
For example:

```
listVal= [(["ank","nki","kit"],21),(["arp","rpi","pit"],22)]
```

Now, I want key-value pairs as

```
 keyval= [("ank",21),("nki",21),("kit",21),("arp",22),("rpi",22),("pit",22)]
```

When I write

```
 keyval= listval.map(lambda x: some_function(x))
```

where some_function() is defined as:

```
def some_function(x):
  shingles=[]
  for i in range(len(x[0])):
    temp=[]
    temp.append(x[0][i])
    temp.append(x[1])
    shingles.append(tuple(temp))
 
  return shingles
```

I don't get the desired output because I think map() returns one key-value pair for an item of the list, not multiple key-value pairs. I have tried other things also and searched on web but did not find anything related to it.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: do you have to use map? map will only return as many elements as it is iterating so it's aproblem

Comment: @jimakr, yes, I have to use only map. This is a part of the problem which is related to data mining where I have to show a list to movie ids for each 3-shingle. So, I have made a pair of list of 3-shingles for each movie and movie-id using map() but since it is a list-a single value pair. So, if I get the output as above, I can use reducedByKey and get the result. If it can be solved by other logic by using map and reduce then can you please tell, if possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so using your limitations this can be done with pyspark's .flatmap()

```
def conversion(n):
    return [(x, n[1]) for x in n[0]]


listVal.flatMap(conversion)
```

or in one line

```
listVal.flatMap(lambda n: [(x, n[1]) for x in n[0]])
```